# Best way to play audio streaming in several format

Tags: java, android, android-service, audio-streaming, android-audiomanager

I'm currently working on a radio application and I'm having some difficulties to figure out the best way to use

```
 - AAC 
 - MP3
 - ...etc
```

Should I create a class for each player and then a service with something like

```
//PRIVATE ATTRIBUTES
private AACPlayer aac;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private AsyncPlayer ap;
private LivePlayer lp;
...etc
```

and then implement every player in this service ?
or maybe create one service per format. But if the application i must use AAC for radio and mp3 for Podcast it'll be troublesome to start two services at the same time...

And note that the radio is playing live streaming (.AAC) so mediaplayer cant play it..

Comment: Android's `MediaPlayer` class should play all the following formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: ah ok, i didn't know, thanks for your comment. Can you make an answer so i can mark it as accepted

Comment: Since you insist :) Thanks, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use Android's built-in [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class.

It should be able to handle the following formats:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

You can always make things more complicated later if you find that it doesn't meet your requirements :)